# Wordpress SMTP EMail

Tags: smtp

I have this plugin on wordpress an already configure class-phpmailer.php to send emails by SMTP. My hosting only accept SMTP emails. When I register in wordpress I receive an email, when I contact anothe user he receives emails. This is ok.

But when I try to use this plugin he doesn't send any emails.
Could you help me please?
Thank you in advance

```
 <?php

ini_set('display_errors',true);
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../wp-config.php';    

$db = new PDO ('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
function update_date_format(){
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
if (strpos($lang, 'pt') > 0){
    $date_format = 'd/m/Y'; // 25/12/2011
}else{
    $date_format = 'd/m/Y'; // 12/25/2011
}
update_option('date_format',$date_format);
}


// get config
$site_url  = get_option ('siteurl');
$from      = get_option ('admin_email');
$blog_name = get_option ('blogname');
$logo      = get_option ('cp_logo');
$date_format = get_option ('date_format');
$link_edit = $site_url.'/'.get_option ('cp_edit_item_url').'/?aid=';

$subject   = get_option ('adsstatsemail_subject');
$header    = get_option ('adsstatsemail_header');
$footer    = get_option ('adsstatsemail_footer');
$campaign  = 'utm_source=Weekly%20Ads%20Stats&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign='.urlencode(get_option ('adsstatsemail_campaign'));
$ad_title  = get_option ('adsstatsemail_adtitle');
$ad_week   = get_option ('adsstatsemail_adweek');
$ad_total  = get_option ('adsstatsemail_adtotal');
$ad_expire = get_option ('adsstatsemail_adexpire');
$ad_edit   = get_option ('adsstatsemail_adedit');

update_date_format();
$week_start = time()-(86400*6);


// replace macros
$header = str_replace ("\n\n", "<br/>", $header);
$header = str_replace ('{date_from}', date($date_format, $week_start), $header);
$header = str_replace ('{today}', date($date_format), $header);
$header = str_replace ('{site_link}', "<a href=\"{$site_url}?{$campaign}\">{$site_url}</a></p><br>", $header);
$header = str_replace ('{site_logo}', "<a href=\"{$site_url}?{$campaign}\"><img src=\"{$logo}\" border=\"0\"/></a></p><br>", $header);

$footer = str_replace ("\n\n", "<br/>", $footer);
$footer = str_replace ('{date_from}', date($date_format, $week_start), $footer);
$footer = str_replace ('{today}', date($date_format), $footer);
$footer = str_replace ('{site_link}', "<a href=\"{$site_url}?{$campaign}\">{$site_url}</a>", $footer);
$footer = str_replace ('{site_logo}', "<a href=\"{$site_url}?{$campaign}\"><img src=\"{$logo}\" border=\"0\"/></a>", $footer);


// fetch ad info
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        p.ID,
        p.post_title,
        p.post_date,
        pm.meta_value AS expireDate,
        u.user_email,
        u.display_name,
        t.postcount AS total,
        SUM(d.postcount) AS week
    FROM 
        wp_posts as p
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID=pm.post_id AND pm.meta_key = 'cp_sys_expire_date'
        INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON u.ID=p.post_author
        INNER JOIN wp_cp_ad_pop_total AS t ON t.postnum=p.ID
        INNER JOIN wp_cp_ad_pop_daily AS d ON d.postnum=p.ID AND d.time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    WHERE
        p.post_type = 'ad_listing'
    GROUP BY p.ID
    ORDER BY u.ID
";

$sth = $db->query ($sql);

$list = array ();
while ($row = $sth->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    // remove expired ads
    if (strtotime($row['expireDate']) <= $week_start) { 
        continue;
    }

    $mail = $row['user_email'];
    unset ($row['user_email']);

    $list[$mail][] = $row;
}


// prepend header
$header = "
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 {$header}
 <table>
<tr>
    <td><b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad_title}</font></b></td>
    <td><b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad_week}</font></b> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad_total}</font></b> &nbsp;</td>
    <td><b><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad_expire}</font></b></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>";

// footer
$footer = "
 </table>
 {$footer}
 </body>
 </html>";


$count = 0;

foreach ($list as $email => $ads) {

    $html = $header;

    foreach ($ads as $ad) {

        $ad['expireDate'] = date($date_format, strtotime ($ad['expireDate']));
        $ad['post_title'] = utf8_encode($ad['post_title']);

        $html .= "
<tr>
    <td><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad['post_title']} &nbsp;</font></td>
    <td><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad['week']}</font></td>
    <td><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad['total']}</font></td>
    <td nowrap><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\">{$ad['expireDate']}</font></td>
    <td nowrap><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\"><a href=\"{$link_edit}{$ad['ID']}&{$campaign}\" target=\"_blank\">{$ad_edit}</a></font></td>
</tr>";

    }

    $html .= $footer;

    $headers = "From: {$blog_name} <{$from}>\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    mail ("{$ad['display_name']} <$email>", $subject, $html, $headers);

    echo "$email\n";
    $count++;
}

echo "\nDone ($count emails).\n\n";
```

Comment: The code you posted does not use PHPMailer at all. It sends the mail using plain ol' PHP `mail()`. See the seventh line from the bottom...

Comment: And its possible change this? How?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line

```
mail ("{$ad['display_name']} <$email>", $subject, $html, $headers);
```

with

```
wp_mail("{$ad['display_name']} <$email>", $subject, $html, $headers);
```

and install the [`WP_Mail_SMTP`](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin which will use SMTP instead of the php `mail()` function.

Comment: One more question. Is posssible make this script send only 700 email / Hour. Could you help me please?

Comment: That's more of server configuration question really. You could probably hack something using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) or use an external server which doesn't have SMTP limits, e.g. [SendGrind](http://sendgrid.com/)

Comment: Also be sure to [mark this as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it has answered your original question! Cheers.